# JButton question

Tags: java, button

Can you disable a JButton without graying out the button itself? 
When you use setEnbaled(false), the button disables and turns to gray. Is it possible to disable the button but make the appearance of the button still the same?

Comment: I would not do this at all because I cannot see how a User would not be confused. Perhaps you can tell us why you need this and there is a different way to do it.

Comment: Agreed.  The button *looks* disabled for a reason.  Otherwise the user will click it expecting something to happen.  And when it doesn't happen, they'll click it *again* and *again* and then complain that your application is broken.

Answer (score 3):

You could ignore the button press in your [ActionListener](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) if a flag is set; however, you should not disable the button without showing it as disabled: it will only confuse the users of your application.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest setting a `ButtonModel` with overridden `setArmed` and `setPressed`. Exactly how you override it depends on exactly what you want it to do - should it appear to be pressed when pressed, for instance? Only set the `ButtonModel` once for a `JButton`. Add or repurpose state on the `ButtonModel` to indicate how you want it o behave at any given moment.

Clearly, GUIs with non-standard behaviour are likely to confuse users.